# Equivalent Ruby .times in Coffeescript

Tags: ruby, coffeescript

What is the most concise equivalent Coffeescript to the following:

```
# ruby    
3.times { puts 'hi' }
```

?

The best I could think of is:

```
# coffeescript
for n in [1..3]
  console.log 'hi'
```

Comment: What's wrong with the snippet you put?

Comment: He's not saying there's anything wrong with it; he's asking for the most concise way to express it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
console.log 'hi' for [1..3]
```

To also handle `0` correctly:

```
console.log 'hi' for [1..n] if n
```

Or with prototype magic:

```
Number::times = (fn) ->
  do fn for [1..@valueOf()] if @valueOf()
  return
3.times -> console.log 'hi'
```

Note that the second method isn't recommended because changing the `Number` prototype has global effects.

*Edit: Changed according to @BrianGenisio's comment (`.prototype.` -> `::`)*

*Edit 2: fixed handling of 0, thanks @Brandon*

Comment: I'm torn between picking your answer or @tokland.

Comment: I picked this answer because it only uses Coffeescript.

Comment: Note that this prototype magic is added by the [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/) library. Really, there's nothing wrong with using prototype magic, as long as only one part of your application is doing it—so you don't have different things expecting different prototype magics.

Comment: Just to play with it a bit, I'd suggest using CoffeeScripts `::` operator:  `Number::times = (fn) ->`  It is the CoffeeScript way :)

Comment: @TrevorBurnham: +1 for mentioning Sugar.js; I have never heard of it before. Looks very useful. Thanks!

Comment: The range should actually be [0...@valueOf()]. As it is currently written, when @valueOf() equals 1, fn is called zero times, and when @valueOf() equals 0, fn is called one time.

Comment: @Brandon `[1..1]` becomes `[1]`, so I'd say it's correct for `@valueOf()==1`. But yes, that zero case needs special handling, thanks for pointing that out. Fixing it.

Comment: I just want to add that in Ruby `n.times` will yield the iteration to the callback function. In other words: `do (-> fn(i-1)) for i in [1..@valueOf()] if @valueOf()` Maybe someone can do it more elegant.

Answer (score 33):

Since you're already using [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) along with CoffeeScript:

```
_(3).times -> console.log('hi')
```

Comment: Yes, I am using underscore.js

Comment: tokland - your answer is actually the one I will use in my code since I use underscore.js, but I picked @thejh's answer because my question asked about Coffeescript. So sorry I couldn't pick your answer. =(

Comment: @NicolasGoy SyntaxError on line 1: `large` is an adjective. One cannot build a `large`.

Comment: @anthropomorphic I deleted my comment, I have no idea what I tried to say.

Comment: @NicolasGoy me either. I vaguely remember writing that comment. Rest assured it was clever.

Answer (score 8):

JavaScript arrays (at least the modern ones) have a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method and CoffeeScript `[1..3]` ranges are arrays so you could do this:

```
[1..3].forEach -> console.log 'hi'
```

One warning though: this might be a bit hard on the browser if your `n` in `[1..n]` is large as you'll be building a large array just to get a convenient notation; but if `n` is small then the overhead of building the array shouldn't matter that much.

Comment: now it produces TypeError: (intermediate value).apply(...).foreach is not a function

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Are you sure about that? [Seems fine](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%5B1..3%5D.forEach%20-%3E%20console.log%20'hi') to me.

Comment: Ohh my mistake, nice solution

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log 'hi' for[]in length:3
```

Comment: *woosh…* don't tell me you actually use that! :)

Comment: I don't understand this code. Could you explain how it works?

Comment: It works though. It produces the following JavaScript: `_ref = {
  length: 3
};
for (_j = 0, _len = _ref.length; _j < _len; _j++) {
  _ref[_j];
  console.log('hi');
}`

Comment: `console.log 'hi' for _ in length:3` is more readable in my opinion. It's very hacky, but it's easy to understand what it does. It also handles `0` correctly without an extra `if`.

Answer (score 0):

using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#times):

```
_.times 3, -> console.log 'hi'
```