# How to convert for loop / while to beautiful coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to convert js

```
var n = 50;
force.start();
for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) force.tick();
force.stop();
```

and I convert to coffeescript with something like this below , just wondering if there is a better way , this one seems longer ? one line / list comprehension ?

```
n = 50
force.start()
i = 0

while i < n
  force.tick()
  ++i
force.stop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
force.tick() for i in [1..50]
```

Transpiles down to:

```
var i, _i;

for (i = _i = 1; _i <= 50; i = ++_i) {
  force.tick();
}
```

If you don't care about the counter var (it's not used in your example) then:

```
force.tick() for [1..50]
```

Which transpiles to:

```
var _i;

for (_i = 1; _i <= 50; _i++) {
  force.tick();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dave Newton gave an example of an inclusive range, using two periods:

```
force.tick() for i in [1..50]
```

You can also use an exclusive range (using three periods), which mimics your original code more closely.

```
force.tick() for i in [0...50]
```

Of course, you can keep `n` as a variable:

```
n = 50
force.tick() for i in [0...n]
```

See
http://elegantcode.com/2011/08/02/exploring-coffeescript-part-5-ranges-loops-and-comprehensions/

If you don't have any need for the variable `i`, you can leave it out:

```
n = 50
force.tick() for [0...n]
```

See [Equivalent Ruby .times in Coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014915/equivalent-ruby-times-in-coffeescript)

Comment: +1, I like leaving out the var when it's not needed.